# Parameter in Dblink Connection - JasperSoft - Postgresql

Tags: jasper-reports

Hi wonder if it is possible to create a dblink connection using a parameter in Jasper. Something like this:

```
SELECT *

FROM ( SELECT * FROM dblink('dbname=db port=5432 host=dbhost user=dbuser password=dbpassword',

'SELECT column_1, column_2, date_in FROM table t WHERE t.date_in >= $P{start_date}') AS check_table(column_1 INTEGER, column_2 text, date_in DATE) ) AS b ORDER BY checkout_number
```

Using de **$P{start_date}** parameter as an internal filter to improve the performance of my query.

I have made some test and looked for some approaches, but so far anything haven't t worked. Anyone has any idea about how to reach this, or this is definitly not allowed?.

Regards